# Coq Program matching on pair

Tags: types, subset, coq

I was trying to do a safe `get` function for list using subset types. I tryied this definition using program

```
Program Fixpoint get A (l : list A) (n : {x : nat | x < length l} ) : A :=
  match (n, l) with
  | (O, x :: l') => x
  | (S n', x :: l') => get l' n'
  | _ => _
  end.
```

The problem is that it get the following error

`Found a constructor of inductive type nat while a constructor of sig
 is expected.`

Why does coq don't let me do a pattern matching in pair containing the subset type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the form for pattern-matching on multiple values is special in Coq. You need to write it like this:

```
Program Fixpoint get A (l : list A) (n : {x : nat | x < length l} ) : A :=
  match n, l with
  | O, x :: l' => x
  | S n', x :: l' => get _ l' n'
  | _, _ => _
  end.
```

In your previous version, you were actually pattern-matching on the pair `(n, l)` instead of pattern-matching on the values `n` and `l` simultaneously, and `Program` was probably getting confused because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `sig` and you're trying to get a nat.  A `sig` is a nat *with* a witness of a proof: https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Specif.html.  You need to match on `proj1_sig n`, which will unpack the number.  You can really think of the notation `{x | P x}` as a tuple (it's a dependent sum, to get technical):

```
Notation "{ x | P }" := (sig (fun x => P)) : type_scope.
```

So whenever you see `{ x | P }` you think of it as `(x,P)`.  The problem is that you're expecting an `n` where you have different type.

Comment: I know it is internally a sig. But with program coq let do things like  

"Program Definition foo (n : {x : nat | x > O}) := match n with O => O | S n' => O end."

I don't known what is the formal reason why It doesn't let do the same thing when pattern matching a pair.